# What's the advantage of using ASP.NET MVC 4 with jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

I recently know that I can also build mobile web applications with ASP.NET MVC 4.

Since several months ago, I've been developing a mobile web application with jQuery Mobile.

The website does not use any .NET technology. It just uses HTML 5, CSS 3 and JavaScript code.

I'm wondering what advantages can I take when I use ASP.NET MVC 4 with jQuery Mobile.

When I read some articles, One of them is only tells that it's good when you run two kinds of websites: One for desktop and another one for mobile.

It looks like that ASP.NET MVC 4 has nothing to do with MVC pattern of JavaScript. To apply MVC pattern I have to use JavaScript MVC pattern libraries.

Can you share any ideas about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET section of your app is the server side where you would traditionally put some background processing or access your database. If you don't have these things then you may not need MVC4 at all.

Comment: Thanks Sav. Simply put, I can utilise server-side technologies.